# Simple-CCSM won't install

Tags: 11.04, compiz, synaptic, dependencies

I'm trying to install `simple-ccsm` 0.8.2-0ubuntu1 in Natty Narwhal, but I receive an error:

```
simple-ccsm:
 Depends: python-compizconfig but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: compizconfig-settings-manager but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.04 uses the new Compiz 0.9. This is quite a significant change, and simple-ccsm simply hasn't been updated yet.

[Bug #738168 has been reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/simple-ccsm/+bug/738168) on Launchpad.

Comment: Correct, I was just looking at that article. I believe CCSM is at v0.9, and Simple-CCSM is at V0.82. Hopefully they can update soon!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **Simple CompizConfig Settings Manager** (aka, **Simple-CCSM**.) is not currently up-to-date with the latest release of **CompizConfig Settings Manager**. Unfortunately, it is not clear when a new update will be released to the public.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the regular compiz settings manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

It will show in the System Settings

- [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)